# Angularjs, Modify/Remove data on form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field in form that I dont want to send. Even though i removed the name on input field it stills get sent probably due to angular magic.

To prevent this I thought if I could remove this item from post request it'd be the solution.

```
<input type='radio' ng-model='birthday' ng-value='true'>
```

when form submits POST has field called birthday despite input not having a name attribute. So how do i prevent it from showing up.

Form is html template, and controller is called on ng-submit

Comment: This is not a question. Provide some code. And what did you try? How did you build this form? How did you link it to the controller? How do you send the form with Ajax?

Comment: updated with information

Comment: Again, provide some code: If you don't event provide the function, which sends the data, how could we imagine, what is going on? Add the function which sends the data, what data is sent and where it is from. Usually, you have one object for all the form data and link it with e.g. `ng-model="form.birthday"`. In the controller you can send then the `$scope.form` object with Ajax to the back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may be looking for the `disabled` property:

```
<input type='radio' ng-model='birthday' ng-value='true' disabled="true">
```

---

**Edited**

Here is an example of how you could use the disabled property for not sending undesired information with the form on submit:

```
<html>

    <body>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);        

            TestApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

              $scope.needsBirthdayDisabled = false;
              $scope.needsBirthday = false;

              $scope.sendForm = function(form) {        

                $scope.needsBirthdayDisabled = true; //if you comment this line, the "yep"'s input value will be sent with the form

                form.$submitted = true;      

              };

            });

        </script>

        <div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">

            <!-- the method is set to GET for test purpose (so we can easily see the sent values on the URL) -->
            <form action="" method="GET" name="myForm" ng-submit="sendForm(this)">

                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"/> 
                </div>

                <div ng-show="needsBirthday">
                    <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
                    <input type="text" name="birthday" ng-model="birthday"/> 
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Needs Birthday</label>               
                    Yep <input type='radio' name="yep" ng-model='needsBirthday' ng-value='true' ng-disabled="needsBirthdayDisabled">                                    
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i can't use this as i want it enabled since it's used to show or hide part of forms but doesn't contain any data that backend should need.

Comment: you can set this property to `true` just before submiting the form, afterwards return it's value to `false` (you can use a scope property for that)

Comment: if validations are run they prevent form submission but value is already set to true

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you an example of how I would do it. I've tested it and it works (no problem with prevent form submission)